# Using MERGE with analytic functions (like RANK) on target table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-warehouse, scd

I have a data pipeline where, at random intervals, the a staging table called `stg` is truncated and overwritten with records. Then, using `MERGE`, the records in `stg` should be merged into the dimension table `dim` according to the following rules (it's a slowly changing dimension of [type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row)):

- when there exists an email in `stg` that doesn't exist in `dim` insert the row corresponding to that email into `dim` with label `'INSERT'`
- when an email *does* exist in both `stg` and `dim` check to see if their corresponding data differs. If so, it's indicative of an `'UPDATE'`.
- when an email is absent from `stg` but does exist in `dim`, this means it's been deleted so label with `'DELETE'`.

Emails are unique to each user in this organization.

```sql
MERGE dim
USING stg
ON stg.email = dim.email
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT(email, first_name, last_name, last_active, dml_type, extraction_timestamp, state_index)
    VALUES(stg.email, stg.first_name, stg.last_name, stg.last_active, 'INSERT', stg.extraction_timestamp))
WHEN MATCHED AND stg.row_hash <> dim.row_hash
    INSERT(email, first_name, last_name, last_active, dml_type, extraction_timestamp, state_index)
    VALUES(stg.email, stg.first_name, stg.last_name, stg.last_active, 'UPDATE', stg.extraction_timestamp)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    INSERT(email, first_name, last_name, last_active, dml_type, extraction_timestamp, state_index)
    VALUES(stg.email, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DELETE', stg.extraction_timestamp)
```

The problem? This query compares `stg` against the entirety of `dim`, when actually I only want to compare it with the following subset of `dim`:

```sql
select *
from (
    select *, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY extraction_timestamp DESC) as rnk 
    from dim
) as hist
where rnk = 1
```

Is it possible for me to `MERGE` with `dim` as my target table, and `stg` as my source, but based only on the `rnk=1` values in as computed in the `RANK()` analytical function shown above?

Something like this?:

```sql
MERGE (
    select *, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY extraction_timestamp DESC) as rnk 
    from dim
) as dim_with_rank
USING stg
ON stg.email = dim_with_rank.email
AND dim_with_rank.rnk = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT(email, first_name, last_name, last_active, dml_type, extraction_timestamp, state_index)
    VALUES(stg.email, stg.first_name, stg.last_name, stg.last_active, 'INSERT', stg.extraction_timestamp))
WHEN MATCHED AND stg.row_hash <> dim.row_hash
    INSERT(email, first_name, last_name, last_active, dml_type, extraction_timestamp, state_index)
    VALUES(stg.email, stg.first_name, stg.last_name, stg.last_active, 'UPDATE', stg.extraction_timestamp)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    INSERT(email, first_name, last_name, last_active, dml_type, extraction_timestamp, state_index)
    VALUES(stg.email, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DELETE', stg.extraction_timestamp)
```

Comment: For a better understanding you want to do the query you are sharing, making use of analytic functions? Or am i mistaken?

Comment: yeah my goal is to be able to find something that achieves what the last query looks like it should do -- a merge where one of the merge conditions (in this case dim_with_rank.rnk = 1) is calculated from the target table (dim) using an analytic function (RANK)

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t run a merge and then launch a subquery as your example:

```
MERGE (
      select *,
  RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY extraction_timestamp DESC) as rnk
  from dim)
as dim_with_rank
USING stg
ON stg.email = dim_with_rank.email
AND dim_with_rank.rnk = 1
```

You would need to create a query like the next one:

```
MERGE dim 
USING (
        select *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY extraction_timestamp DESC) as rnk
        from stg )
 as stg_with_rank
 ON stg_with_rank.email = dim.email AND
 stg_with_rank.rnk = 1 [...]
```

You can see more information about this use case [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement)